# Two seemingly identical pieces of code having different results (passing pointers to structures)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I created the following code just now to help debug a C project we have to write that basically is eventually supposed to emulate a UNIX file system. I've been pulling my hairs out trying to figure out why two seemingly identical blocks of code produce different output. When I simulate the same behavior that my function mkfs() is supposed to have by typing the same lines of code in the main() file, it works perfectly, but when I try to use the function (literally the same lines of code!!!!!!), it simply says RUN FAILED. When I execute the code inside my main() function that is currently commented out, it works great and indeed prints "/" to the console, but when I try to create a pointer to a filesystem, call mkfs() on it, then print out the same string, it just doesn't work.

I must be not understanding something. Here is the code, but if you prefer syntax highlighting then here is a little link to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/9yCB1iND

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct directory {
    const char *name;
    struct file *f;
    struct directory *dir;
} Directory;

typedef struct file {
    const char *name;
    struct file *next;
    struct file *prev;
    Directory *parent;
} File;

typedef struct filesystem {
    Directory *rt;
    Directory *cd;
} Filesystem;

/* The function mkfs() initializes the Filesystem. It takes a pointer to a 
 * filesystem as its single parameter and allocates the memory needed ( it 
 * allocates the space needed to accomodate the two Directory pointers 
 * that a filesystem has). */
    void mkfs(Filesystem *files){

    /*The first malloc creates enough space for Filesystem itself*/
    files = malloc(sizeof(Filesystem));

    /*The second malloc creates enough space for a root Directory*/
    files->rt = malloc(sizeof(Directory));

    /*We make a character array with a single slash that represents root*/
    char nv[] = "/";
    /* nv is a pointer to the first element in the array nv[]. 
     * We point 'files->rt->name' to the first character in the array nv[]. */
    files->rt->name = nv;
    /* Finally, we set files->cd to point to whatever files->rt pointed too, 
     * which is the current directory "/" */
    files->cd = files->rt;
}


int main(void) {
    /*
    Filesystem *files;
    files = malloc(sizeof(Filesystem));
    files->rt = malloc(sizeof(Directory));
    char nv[] = "/";
    files->rt->name = nv;
    files->cd = files->rt;
    printf("%s", files->cd->name);

        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Why does the FOLLOWING code not work when the ABOVE code should be "the same" ?
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    Filesystem *f;
    mkfs(f);
    printf("%s", f->cd->name);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mkfs` function:

```
char nv[] = "/";
files->rt->name = nv;
```

`nv` is an array with automatic storage duration, lifetime of which ends when the execution goes out of the scope of this function making `files->rt->name` becoming *dangling pointer*, dereferencing of which leads to ***undefined behavior***. You need to allocate `files->rt->name` dynamically.

Also note that `mkfs` function takes pointer to `Filesystem`, which is just a copy of the pointer passed to it. Changes made to the pointer itself are not visible to the caller, which means that when you call `printf("%s", f->cd->name);`, you are dereferencing uninitialized pointer, which also leads to ***undefined behavior***. If you want `mkfs` to allocate the memory and initialize your pointer correctly, then you should pass an address of this pointer:

```
void mkfs(Filesystem **files) {
    *files = malloc(sizeof(Filesystem));
    (*files)->rt = malloc(sizeof(Directory));
    char nv[] = "/";
    (*files)->rt->name = malloc(strlen(nv) + 1);
    strcpy((*files)->rt->name, nv);
    (*files)->cd = (*files)->rt;
}

int main(void) {
    Filesystem *f = NULL;  // <-- it's good to keep your variables initialized
    mkfs(&f);
    ...
}
```

And in case you don't need your function to make changes to the memory this pointer points to, but not to the pointer itself, it could look like this:

```
void mkfs(Filesystem *files) {
    files->rt = malloc(sizeof(Directory));
    char nv[] = "/";
    files->rt->name = malloc(strlen(nv) + 1);
    strcpy(files->rt->name, nv);
    (*files)->cd = files->rt;
}

int main(void) {
    Filesystem *f;
    f = malloc(sizeof(Filesystem));
    mkfs(f);
    ...
}
```

Comment: So if I made nv a global variable just so that I can initially name the first directory created "/", that should fix the dangling pointer issue right? But then allocating files->rt->name dynamically just means using malloc(sizeof("/")), right? I just want to make sure I understand what you mean. Thanks

Comment: Right that definitely makes sense, just like how in order to make a linked list be able to work without head pointing to anything initially, you must pass a pointer to a pointer to a Node in order to be able to directly modify what the first pointer is pointing to. However, the function declarations we were given state that we must simply use void mkfs(Filesystem *files) and not a double pointer, but I guess I could make a helper function to get around that

Comment: @HeraldD.Precursor: Check the code in my answer now. I edited it :)

Comment: Wow thanks so much, it makes no sense to me why his function prototypes would look this:http://pastebin.com/XULyjzzS

Comment: Could I just get around this by making the Filesystem a pointer? Like the logic of it makes perfect sense, you want to actually modify what you are pointing to so you pass in the address of that pointer itself since in C everything is passed by value and copies are made. Would making the Filesystem type a pointer (if possible) allow the function prototype mkfs(Filesystem *files) to work? I really appreciate the assistance, I am going to continue to try and look at more examples of structures containing pointers to other structures in order to understand better. Once again thanks.

Comment: @HeraldD.Precursor: The key point here is that your function allocates some memory and makes this pointer to point to this memory. Changes to pointer itself are not visible to the caller. If you allocate the memory in `main` and this pointer will point to valid instance of `Filesystem`, then you can pass it to function and changes to memory, where this pointer points to will be visible to the caller :)

Comment: @HeraldD.Precursor: I added example of the second scenario too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27161/discussion-between-herald-d-precursor-and-liho)

Answer (score 2):

When you make a call like this

```
mkfs(f);
```

A copy of `f` is passed to mkfs.
That copy is the one which is changed (i.e the return value of malloc is used to initialize that copy. However, the `f` in `main` is not changed.

Hence when you do

```
printf("%s", f->cd->name);
```

in main - it's undefined behaviour because you are accessing an uninitialized pointer.

There are also other problems in your program

Your `nv` is local to the function. It's life is only till the function returns. So that's wrong.